# Cannot create algorithm for a sequence in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

After hours of work I give up as I do not see the solution anymore.

I therefore ask for your help to create following sequence:

for example given is the start code:  6D082A

The 1st position ("A") is from an array with 16 elements in this sequence:
Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")

the 3rd to 5th position (082) has values from 000 to 999
the 2nd position ("D") has values from "A" to "Z"
the 1st position (6) has values from 1-9

So the sequence from the example code above is:
6D082A
6D082B
6D082C
..
6D082F
6D0830
6D0831
....
6D083F
6D0840
...
6D999F
6E0000
....
6Z999F
7A0000
....
9Z999F which is the absolut last code in this sequence

Whith all the loops within the counters I am lost!

At the end the user should also enter the given first code and the number of codes he wants.
My last trial was (without any start-code and any variable number of codes to create.

```
Sub Create_Barcodes_neu2()
Dim strErsterBC As String
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim str6Stelle As Variant
Dim intStart6  As Integer
Dim str6  As String
Dim i As Integer, ii As Integer, Index As Integer

'On Error Resume Next
Dim v As Variant
str6Stelle = Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")  '16 Elemente

strErsterBC = InputBox("Enter the first Barcode.", "Barcode-Generator")
intRow = InputBox("Enter the number of barcodes to create.", "Barcode-Generator")
intStart6 = ListIndex(Mid(strErsterBC, 6, 1), str6Stelle)
str35stelle = CInt(Mid(strErsterBC, 3, 3))  'Zahl 000-999

str2stelle = Mid(strErsterBC, 2, 1)   letters A-Z
str1stelle = Left(strErsterBC, 1)

'Debug.Print str6Stelle(1); vbTab; str6Stelle(2); vbTab; str6Stelle(15); vbTab; str6Stelle(16)
For Z = 0 To 32
    ausgabe6 = i + intStart6
    i = i + 1
    ausgabe35 = str35stelle
    ausgabe2 = i3
    ausgabe1 = i4
    If i = 16 Then
       i = 0
       i2 = i2 + 1
       ausgabe35 = i2 + str35stelle
        If i2 = 999 Then
            ausgabe35 = 999
            i2 = 0
            i3 = i3 + 1

            If i3 = 26 Then
                ausgabe2 = 26
                i3 = 1
                i4 = i4 + 1

                If i4 > 9 Then
                MsgBox "Ende"
                Exit Sub
                End If

            End If

        End If

    End If

st6 = str6Stelle(ausgabe6)
st35 = Format(ausgabe35, "000")
ausgabe2 = Chr(i3)
ausgabe1 = i4
    Next Z

End Sub
```

Hope you can help me in my solution!
Thanks a lot!
Michael

Comment: So if the user enters "3" then he gets 6D082A, 6D082B, 6D082C if he gives 6D082A as first barcode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for:

```
Option Explicit

Const MAX_FIRST_DEC_NUMBER As Integer = 9
Const MAX_MIDDLE_DEC_NUMBER As Integer = 999
Const MAX_LAST_HEX_NUMBER As Long= &HF

Sub Makro()

    Dim codes() As String
    Dim startCode As String
    Dim numOfBarcodes As Integer

    startCode = "0A0000" ' Starting with the "lowest" barcode

    ' Maximum number of barcodes = 4,160,000 because:
                         '0-9' *     'A-Z' *     '0-9' *     '0-9' *     '0-9' *     'A-F'
    numOfBarcodes =  CLng(10)  * CLng(26)  * CLng(10)  * CLng(10)  * CLng(10)  * CLng(16)

    codes = CreateBarcodes(startCode , numOfBarcodes)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To numOfBarcodes - 1
        Debug.Print codes(i)
    Next

End Sub


' NOTE: Given "9Z999F" as start code will give you a numberOfBarcodes-sized array with
' one valid barcode. The rest of the array will be empty. There is room for improvement.
Function CreateBarcodes(ByVal start As String, ByVal numberOfBarcodes As Long) As String()

    ' TODO: Check if "start" is a valid barcode
    ' ...

    ' Collect barcodes:

    Dim firstDecNumber As Integer
    Dim char As Integer
    Dim middleDecNumber As Integer
    Dim lastLetter As Integer

    ReDim barcodes(0 To numberOfBarcodes - 1) As String

    For firstDecNumber = Left(start, 1) To MAX_FIRST_DEC_NUMBER Step 1

        For char = Asc(Mid(start, 2, 1)) To Asc("Z") Step 1

            For middleDecNumber = CInt(Mid(start, 3, 3)) To MAX_MIDDLE_DEC_NUMBER Step 1

                For lastLetter = CInt("&H" + Mid(start, 6, 1)) To MAX_LAST_HEX_NUMBER Step 1

                    numberOfBarcodes = numberOfBarcodes - 1

                    barcodes(numberOfBarcodes) = CStr(firstDecNumber) + Chr(char) + Format(middleDecNumber, "000") + Hex(lastLetter)

                    If numberOfBarcodes = 0 Then
                        CreateBarcodes = barcodes
                        Exit Function
                    End If

                Next

            Next

        Next

    Next

    CreateBarcodes = barcodes

End Function
```

Output:

```
9Z999F
9Z999E
9Z999D
...
1A0001
1A0000
0Z999F
0Z999E
...
0B0002
0B0001
0B0000
0A999F
0A999E
...
0A0011
0A0010
0A000F
0A000E
...
0A0003
0A0002
0A0001
0A0000
```

Comment: Hi Stefan!
Thanks your reply but I do not get any barcode as output, no error msg either.

michael

Comment: @user3480989 Did you try to debug it? This should run out of the box. Set a breakpoint *after* the `CreateBarcodes` call and look if `codes` contains some values.

Comment: Hi Stefan!
Sorry, I had your code in a module with other code so it could not run, maybe due to the missung constants.
Now, it starts to create the barcodes but at the last position the sequence should be like my array showed
Array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), meaning that after "F" the next code starts with "0", the next has "1", etc.

And further your codes are descending. I need them ascending. Exact your output from bottom to top.
Thanks yr. help!
Michael

Comment: Which array? My algorithm just takes a barcode and generates `numOfBarcodes`-barcodes from that starting position. This should work from `0A0000` to `9Z999F`.

Comment: Well, you don't use an array. I mentioned the array only to show the sequence I need.
The sequence is from 0-9 and A-F.
This sequence concerns only the 6th position.
The 3-5 position has a "normal" ascending sequence from 000-999.
The 2nd position from A-Z.
The 1st position from 0-9.

Comment: @user3480989 I don't use an array because 0-F is just a hexadecimal number. No need for an array I can just `Hex(number)` for `number <= 15`. I don't need an array for `A-Z` because I can get their integer numbers with `Asc(char)` and so on ..

Comment: call `CreateBarcodes` with `CreateBarcodes("0A0000", 4160000)` where `10*26*10*10*10*16 = 4160000` and set a breakpoint right after this call. You will see that all codes are generated correctly. Note if you print that to your console this will take a while, just set a breakpoint and inspect the resulting codes

Comment: Stefan!
Your codes are CORRECT, but DESCENDING and not ASCENDING!!
9Z999F
9Z999E
9Z999D

It should be
9Z9997
9Z9998
9Z9999
9Z999A
9Z999B
9Z999D
9Z999E
9Z999F

Comment: @user3480989 Are you serious? You get a *sorted* array of barcodes. Just iterate from `For idx = Ubound(codes) To 0 Step - 1` or change the algorithm. You'd only need to add a counter to `CreateBarcodes` that increments until it is equal to `numberOfBarcodes` and use it as index for the resulting array but this is pointless since the array is already sorted ... If you can't even do that than you should solve that problem first. Viel Spaß.

Comment: Stefan!
Ich probiers mal auf deutsch.Danke für Deine Hilfe, aber m.M. ist die Reihenfolge Deines Ergebnisses absteigend und nicht aufsteigend.Außerdem bekomme ich ja immer nur an der 6.Position A-F und nicht 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F. Weil CInt("&H" + Mid(start, 6, 1)) To MAX_LAST_HEX_NUMBER Step 1  eben zufällig bei "A" beginnt. Nach dem Erreichen des ersten "F" muß die letzte Stelle aber bei 0 beginnen, dann 1, dann 2, etc.
Wenn der erste barcode zufällig so wäre "6D082E", dann gäbe es ja nur E und F Endungen.
Sorry, bin nicht so fit in VBA, dass ich mit Arrays umgehen kann. 
Michael

Comment: Sorry mir ist noch immer nicht ganz klar was du meinst. Der "kleinste" Code sollte `0A0000` sein oder? Wenn du `CreateBarcodes("0A0000", 16)` aufrufst bekommst du alle codes von `0A0000` bis `0A000F`. Mit 17 kommst du bis `0A0010`, mit 18 bis `0A0011` etc. wie oben in meinem output beschrieben. Im array das zurückt kommt sind sie *absteigend* sortiert, das ist natürlich richtig, aber man iteriert dann eben entweder vom ende zum anfang oder ändert das im Algorithmus entsprechend (kein großer Aufwand)

Answer (score 0):

The approach to the right algorithm is to think of a number in the following way:
Let's take a normal decimal 3-digit number. Each digit can take one element of an ordered set of symbols, 0-9.
To add 1 to this number, we exchange the rightmost symbol for the next symbol (2 becomes 3 etc.) - but if it is already the 'highest' possible symbol ("9"), 
then reset it to the first possible symbol ("0"), and increase the next digit to the left by one.
So 129 becomes 130, and 199 has two carrying overflows and becomes 200. If we had 999 and tried and inc by one, we'd have a final overflow.
Now this can be easily done with any set of symbols, and they can be completely different for every digit.

In the code, you store the symbol sets for every digit. And the "number" itself is stored as an array of indexes, pointing to which symbol is
used at each position. These indexes can easily be increased.
In case of an overflow for a single digit, the function IncByOne is called recursively for the next position to the left.

This is code for a class `clSymbolNumber`

```
Option Explicit

' must be a collection of arrays of strings
Public CharacterSets As Collection
' <code> must contain integers, the same number of elements as CharacterSets
' this is the indices for each digit in the corresponding character-set
Public code As Variant

Public overflowFlag As Boolean

Public Function IncByOne(Optional position As Integer = -1) As Boolean
    IncByOne = True
    If position = -1 Then position = CharacterSets.Count - 1
    ' overflow at that position?
    If code(position) = UBound(CharacterSets(position + 1)) Then
        If position = 0 Then
            overflowFlag = True
            IncByOne = False
            Exit Function
        Else
            ' reset this digit to lowest symbol
            code(position) = 0
            ' inc the position left to this
            IncByOne = IncByOne(position - 1)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Else
        code(position) = code(position) + 1
    End If
End Function

Public Sub class_initialize()
    overflowFlag = False
    Set CharacterSets = New Collection
End Sub

Public Function getCodeString() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s As String
    s = ""
    For i = 0 To UBound(code)
        s = s & CharacterSets(i + 1)(code(i))
    Next
    getCodeString = s
End Function
```

Testing sub in a worksheet module - this outputs all possible "numbers" with the given test data.

```
Sub test()
    Dim n As New clSymbolNumber
    n.CharacterSets.Add Array("1", "2", "3")
    n.CharacterSets.Add Array("a", "b")
    n.CharacterSets.Add Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
    n.CharacterSets.Add Array("1", "2", "3")
    ' start code (indexes)
    n.code = Array(0, 0, 0, 0)
    ' output all numbers until overflow
    Dim row As Long
    row = 2
    Me.Columns("A").ClearContents
    While Not n.overflowFlag
        Me.Cells(row, "A") = n.getCodeString
        n.IncByOne ' return value not immediately needed here
        row = row + 1
        DoEvents
    Wend
    MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks your reply but it does not work. sub test ends with an error 'index was outside bounds of array' not marking any line in code. And I could not find the possibility to enter the start code (e.g. "6D082A") and the numer of codes I want to be created.

Comment: In my test the code works (without any changes). Step through the test sub (F8) line by line, then you'll see where the error is. Note that CharacterSets and code need the same number of elements. - But yes, you'd have to write a sub that converts a start code into indexes, should not be very difficult - just look up each character in the according characterSet to get each index.