# vb.net Pair Combinations to Create All Possible Sets

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I need help figuring out how to go about programming this problem.  I have an unknown number of pairs.  Each pair is a Length x Width.  I want to create sets of every possible combination of either a Length or Width from each pair.  Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

If I input 3 pairs, (1x2) (3x4) (5x6) I would get the following sets:
(1,3,5) (1,3,6) (1,4,5) (1,4,6) (2,3,5) (2,3,6) (2,4,5) (2,4,6)

So if I had 4 pairs, it would create a total of 16 sets, etc.  I need to be able to input each pair and after all pairs have been entered, I need it to print out the sets.  It can never include both numbers from a given pair in the same set.  How do I create a loop or is there a built in math function that could produce all possible sets from a given number of pair inputs?  I hope I described the problem well enough but if not, please ask questions.  Thanks

Comment: The algorithm I posted [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326734/cannot-create-algorithm-for-a-sequence-in-vba/25328933#25328933) works well for that and it's quite easy. It's still more powerful than for your case (the 'pairs' could be sets of different size), so there may be a simpler way (although that one is really short as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Cartesian product.

For example, if we have two sets A and B, such that

```
A = {1,2}

B = {3,4}
```

Then the result of the Cartesian product A x B is equal to

```
A x B = {(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)}
```

If now we want to make the Cartesian product between the result obtained above and a new set, for example:

```
N = {5,6}
```

The result of the Cartesian product A x B x N, is equal to

```
A x B = {(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)}
N = {5,6}
──────────────────────────────────────────────────
A x B x N = {(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,4,5),(1,4,6),(2,3,5),(2,3,6),(2,4,5),(2,4,6)}
```

Each element of the first set must be paired with each element of the second set.

I have developed 4 solutions to the Cartesian product:

1. Using a mathematical model, but without recursion. This solution
   vectors using calculating for each combination number.
2. Using recursion, with the Collections class.
3. using the List (Of ...) class, also with recursion.

These three solutions seemed to me difficult to explain to you.
Furthermore, it is very difficult for me to explain my thoughts in English, because my native language is Castilian.

So I made the effort to create another solution that does not use recursion, which was more simple and friendly for any programmer.

Finally, I could create a satisfactory solution. Easy to understand and without recursion.
It is also very versatile. Any number of sets is accepted, as required, from 2 onwards.
You can also use any number of items. This depends on the requirements of each developer.

I hope this 4th. solution I devised, will please you, esteemed colleagues.

Only need a ListBox1 within Form4. Here it is:

```
Public Class Form4

    Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        '┌─────────── Temporary code for example ───────────┐
        Dim Set_1 As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim Set_2 As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim Set_3 As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

        Set_1.Add("1")
        Set_1.Add("2")

        Set_2.Add("3")
        Set_2.Add("4")

        Set_3.Add("5")
        Set_3.Add("6")
        '└──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

        Dim Sets As List(Of Object) = New List(Of Object)

        Sets.Add(Set_1)
        Sets.Add(Set_2)
        Sets.Add(Set_3)

        Dim product As List(Of String) = Sets(0)

        For i = 1 To Sets.Count - 1
            product = CartesianProduct(product, Sets(i))
        Next

        For Each element As String In product
            Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(element)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Function CartesianProduct(ByVal Set_A As List(Of String), ByVal Set_B As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)

        Dim product As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

        For Each a As String In Set_A
            For Each b As String In Set_B
                product.Add(a & b)
            Next
        Next

        Return product
    End Function
End Class
```

Have a nice day! :)